# how to create a sorted list in WinJs?

Tags: javascript, listview, winjs

I am currently trying to create a list which is sorted by a key for a two page Win 8 Metro styled App.
First I create two new **WinJS.Binding.List** from my Data Array

```
var itemList = new WinJS.Binding.List(dataItems);
var list = new WinJS.Binding.List(dataItems);
```

Next I create my filtered list

```
Data.updateGroup(options)

function updateGroup(key) {  
list = itemList.createFiltered(function (itemList) { return itemList.group == key; });
}
```

And then I assign this list to my listView

```
listView.itemDataSource = Data.list.dataSource;
listView.itemTemplate = element.querySelector(".itemtemplate");
listView.layout = new ui.ListLayout();
```

But when I launch my App the unfiltered list is shown.

What do I have to change ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sorted projection of a WinJS.Binding.List using its [createSorted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700743.aspx) method, to which you provide the sorting function in which you'll use your key.

The return of createSorted is a derivative of WinJS.Binding.List, so you can then call createFiltered on that once your filter is known.

In other words, the projections of a List are composable, so you can chain the projection methods together, e.g. createSorted().createFiltered() or createFiltered().createSorted(). Same works with createGrouped as well.

Comment: this is what i made in the second code box, but its still not working

Comment: Ehm Im not sure about any issues with stackoverflow but I posted the important parts of the code, here is a screenshot of my Question.
[link](http://www.imagebanana.com/view/bvdzej1e/Unbenannt.jpg)

Comment: Looking at your code there are two problems. First, just declare var list = null; at the beginning because the one you create with new will be overwritten (and gc'd) by your call to createFiltered.

Second, when you set up the ListView you're using Data.list.dataSource but your list variable is in the global namespace and not the Data namespace. So I'm not entirely sure what List is actually showing up in the ListView. My guess is that your Data.updateGroups method is assigning the result from createFiltered to a different variable than Data.list.